# how to block all sites except few in all Browsers of windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, browser, website, blocking

I have seen in companies that there's employees cannot access all websites except few which are related to company on their computer, but they can't access sites like facebook, Quora,youtube, stackexchange. I don't know how they manage to block this websites in windows 7 system. is there any method to unblock them from client computer. 
don't give me solution to block Internet explorer here. as these websites are block from all the browsers.

Comment: It will be a network or firewall block. Nothing to do with the client computer.

Comment: then tell me how they block computer from Network or firewall?

Comment: Generally, this is done on a proxy computer using software, such as a product called **WebSense**, though it can also be done by a dedicated device such as a **Web Security Appliance**.

Comment: Are you asking for advice on how to bypass your company's security policy?

Answer (score 0):

What you have to understand is that nothing is specifically blocked on your computer, and that's not browser-specific. Instead, traffic is filtered by a machine on the network, often the outside node (the one linking the local (LAN) network, where your computer is, to the internet (WAN), in your case, the web, where Facebook or Google's servers are installed).

This network node is called a [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server), i.e a server that intercepts and analyses the requests your computer does, before they're sent sent over the internet. It matches the requests' infos with a list of filters, which has been defined by your system administrator.

The easiest way to achieve this is by blocking the DNS (Domain Name System) requests. DNS is the protocol which translates a domain name to an IP address. This can be easily bypassed by connecting using the server's IP address directly. E.g: use `216.58.208.206` instead of `google.com`.

The other way to achieve such blocking, is by reading the metadata or even the content of the packets your PC will send to the distant server. This is called [DPI (Deep Packet Inspection)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_packet_inspection). The proxy will try to find something in the data who can identify the website you're travelling on. This can hardly bypassed, because some nodes will block VPNs and will try to decrypt the ssl traffic (by tricking your PC to use their certificate instead of the server's one).